# Property attributes for Windows 10 Universal custom control?

Tags: c#, windows-10, win-universal-app

I'm creating my first Windows 10 Universal Windows Platform (UWP) app.  I'm creating a custom templated control to use in it.  I've successfully created a DependencyProperty and exposed its value through a standard .NET property.  My issue is applying a CategoryAttribute and DescriptionAttribute to the property so it shows in the correct section of the property grid and with the correct description.  My custom control project references UniversalWindows.  Is there some other reference I need to add?

Answer (score -1):

You may need to create Design-Time library to [provide Design-Time metadata](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee849819(v=vs.110).aspx). The library should be a WPF C# library.

The library should reference Microsoft.Windows.Design.Extensibility.dll and Microsoft.Windows.Design.Interaction.dll. Then, in the library you should have a class that inherit from [IProvideAttributeTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windows.design.metadata.iprovideattributetable(v=vs.110).aspx) interface to provide metadata attributes.

This is very complex， for more detail see [WPF Designer Extensibility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546938(v=vs.110).aspx) .